# How do I use drawAtPoint to place an image in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, image, uiimage

So I'm trying to get an image to appear at a specific point. I've  seen some stuff about drawInRect, but I'm not sure why this code isn't working with drawAtPoint. Here is what I'm using.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
CGPoint kitty;
kitty.x = 144;
kitty.y = 144;
[image drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)kitty];
```

I've also tried this with cGPointMake and just putting the coordinates right after that. Neither method will display the image, yet neither raises an error message. What am I missing?

Comment: I meant which subclass of UIView?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I have a vague idea on how to set up a UIView subclass, but not how it works with the code I have above. I'm making shots in the dark here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it to work I needed to make a subclass of UIView and I put this in it:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(curPoint.x,curPoint.y) ];
}
```

The other thing I was missing was the setNeedsDisplay method, which I used in the ViewController.m file.

Answer (score 0):

use a UIImageView. It's a specific object for dealing images.

// in pseudo code:

```
UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myImage.png"]
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: anImage];
(UIView*)[self addChild: imageView];
imageView.center = (CGPoint){10, 20};
```

drawrect: should be used for specifik task, it's a template pattern and u should use it to update some GUI logic. Read apple doc for further details  (by the way i rarely use it)